# Unexpected character '@' from [script.*.js]

Tags: javascript, angular, build

When I try to production build angular, i encountered the error 'Unexpected character '@' [scripts.*.js]'. Production command ng build --prod

Angular version: 7.*
Node modules used : 
1. ag-grid

Comment: Can you take a screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When anyone gets the error 'Unexpected character '@' [scripts.*.js]' or 'Unexpected token ',' [scripts.*.js]'. The above error could be from our code or the node_modules which we would have installed.

Error :
[You can see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg6ND.png)

To find the source,
execute the command ***ng build --prod --source-map***

After executing source map, we can get the source file that causes error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uND3I.png)

The above command would point us to the file that causes the error while taking a production build.

If the command doesn't point to the source, please ensure that **sourcemap=true** in angular.json for production is true

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs for eg. if you accidentally have a css-file in the scripts section in the angular.json